# Не могу обработать сигналы по нажатию кнопок Ok и Cancel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python-3.x, gui, pyqt5

Все, что я нашла в интернете и попробовала закоментированно. Ни один из этих вариантов мне не помог. Подскажите, что я делаю не так? 
Вот часть кода:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDialog

class Ui_MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, MainWindow):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()
        #много кода
        self.buttons = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.buttons.setObjectName("buttons")
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonBox.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.buttonBox.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.buttonBox.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Save|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Apply|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)

        self.buttonBox.button(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok).clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.button(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel).clicked.connect(self.reject)
#        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(QDialog.accept)
#        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(QDialog.reject)
#        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()"), AboutDialog.accept)
#        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("rejected()"), AboutDialog.reject)
#        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
#        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
#        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
#        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.buttons.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
        #много кода
```

Этот диалог вызывается из другого виджета по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: Не понятно, что же конкретно у вас не получается? Код рабочий, слоты `accept` и `reject` выполняются. Если вам нужно получить результат выполнения этого диалога, то в месте вызова проверяйте возвращаемое значение функции `Ui_MainWindow.exec_()`.

Comment: Не понятно, что же конкретно у вас не получается? Код рабочий, слоты `accept` и `reject` выполняются. Если вам нужно получить результат выполнения этого диалога, то в месте вызова проверяйте возвращаемое значение функции `Ui_MainWindow.exec_()`.